# Divergent Series as a topic of research

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

About a year ago, while studying real analysis, I got very much interested in divergent series. I discussed possible research topics related to divergent series with my teachers but couldn't find any. But one of my teachers suggested the book by G. H. Hardy, titled **Divergent Series**. Recently, I was lucky to get hold of this book in our college library. In the preface of this book, J. E. Littlewood quotes Abel:

> Divergent Series are the invention of the devil, and it is shameful to base on them any demonstration whatsoever.

Also, I came across an article by Christiane Rousseau, titled [*Divergent series: past, present, future*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5712), but the point of view presented there is limited to differential equations and dynamical systems.

As per my knowledge, *Riemann's Zeta Function* is an important historical example of divergent series. But I don't know as of now whether people doing research in **Analytic Number Theory** are still interested in general theory of Divergent Series.

I want to know that if there are *Number Theorists* doing research in *Divergent Series*. In case there are people doing research in this field, what are the topics of their interest?

Comment: Shchepin Evgeny http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?personid=8985&option_lang=&option_lang=eng

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Thanks! Happy to know that people are still interested in Divergent Series, but he is a Topologist.

Comment: I think, now this field is called 'Tauberian theory'.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks! Can you please elaborat e the recent developments in Number Theory due to Tauberian theory? Though as per Wikipedia "Hardy and Littlewood developed a proof of the prime number theorem based on their tauberian theorem"

Comment: I recommend nice book by Korevaar on Tauberian theory, it contains applications to Number Theory.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Looks promising, but it's not in our college library. It would be really useful if you could share your personal opinions about the relationships between Tauberian theory and number theory as an answer below.

Comment: The Riemann zeta-function at $s=1$ diverges, but elsewhere the zeta-function itself is *not* divergent; its values beyond ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ come from analytic continuation, not from any theory of divergent series.

Comment: I am talking about how you should think about the zeta-function today, or for the last 150 years for that matter, not how Euler worked with it.

Comment: @KCo, can't one interpret analytic continuation as a technique for summing divergent series?

Comment: @GerryMyerson ... not in the sense found (e.g.) in Hardy's book.  If a series diverges to $+\infty$, then, after applying any regular summation method, it still diverges to $+\infty$.  Summation methods are useful when a series diverges by oscillation.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : I don't see why. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$ "converges to $+\infty$" very nicely, but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n z^n = \frac{1}{1-2z}$ for $|z| < 1/2$ and Abel's summation method gives $\displaystyle\overset{Abel \ Sum}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty} 2^n = \lim_{z \to 1} \frac{1}{1-2z} = -1$

Comment: @user1952009 ... That is not Abel summation ... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation which is only for the boundary of the circle of convergence.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : ok maybe, so you are saying that Abel never considered any analytic continuation summation method, but only the simpler case of exploiting the continuity of the power series at the boundary of the disk ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some respects the theory of divergent series is still a very important part of number theory.

A large part of number theory concerns the study of Dirichlet series

$$f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$
for some $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and some complex parameter $s \in \mathbb{C}$. Provided the $a_n$ satisfy some mild growth conditions, this series is absolutely convergent in some half-plane $\mathrm{Re}(s) > \sigma_0$.

One then wants to try to analytically continue this Dirichlet series to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ and understand its zeros and poles. Analytic continuation replaces the classical treatment of divergent series by something more rigorous.

Important cases where one has an analytic continuation are for the Riemann zeta function and Dirichlet $L$-functions. Studying the analytic properties of Dirichlet series coming from Galois representations and automorphic forms is a very active area of research (the Langlands program).

Comment: Just to add one other important case where one now knows analytic continuation: for the $L$-series attached to elliptic curves defined over $\mathbb Q$ (Wiles's theorem). The impact of the work of Wiles et al. on current research is huge.

Comment: Can you please elaborat, how analytic continuation replaces the classical treatment of divergent series by something more rigorous.

Comment: @rationalbeing: As an example, it allows you to make sense of [Ramanujan's "formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) $1 +  2 + 3 +\cdots = -1/12$. Namely that, once one has obtained an analytic continuation of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta$, we have $\zeta(-1) = -1/12$.

Comment: @DanielLoughran : Since now we have better tools from complex analysis. In your opinion, would it be useful to go through Hardy's book on Divergent Series?

Comment: @rationalbeing: Unfortunately I have not read Hardy's book, so I cannot advise you there. However, my personal opinion and gut feeling is that things have moved on a lot since Hardy wrote this book, and if you are interested in doing modern mathematical research then divergent series are not really the way to go. I would recommend that you learn some analytic number theory instead. A good introduction for me was "Apostol - Introduction to Analytic Number Theory". More advanced topics at the forefront of modern research can be found in "Iwaniec, Kowalski - Analytic Number Theory".

Comment: and most Dirichlet series are not meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ when analytically continuated, some of them indeed cannot be continuated. but all the $\zeta$ functions are (which is part of the miracle, one of the explanation being the theory of modular/automorphic forms)

Answer (score -8):

There are different procedures for extracting a real number from a divergent series.  We tend to say:

$$ 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots = \frac{1}{2} $$

and we use the Cesaro averages as a rule to .  Lately I am personally of the school that the partial sums are of two values;

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^N (-1)^n = \left\{  \begin{array}{cl} 1 &  n \text{ is odd} \\ 0 & n \text{ is even} \end{array} \right. $$

Then there is some type of limit, but the result is not a real number - an element of $\mathbb{R}$ - it is a **distribution**.  We could try to say:

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^N (-1)^n \approx \frac{1}{2}\delta_{0} + \frac{1}{2}\delta_1$$

Divergent series come up as part of regluarization in physics, which are attempts to get finite numbers when the aren't any.  As an avid reader of `hep-th` I can attest to physicsts at prominent institutions, casually assigning finite value to bad divergent sums and integrals.

The methods in Hardy's divergent series book or the theory of distributions will formalize such an intuition.

---

Many discussions end the conversation when they establish a particular series is divergent.  Hardy's approach seem to study how the series diverges and establish a rate of divergence.  Here is one of his result on the theta function. Let $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$, and $q = re^{2\pi i n x} \in \mathbb{D}$ then

$$ 1 + 2 \sum q^{n^2} = o\left( \sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{1-r}}\right) $$

Although I am slightly confused since if the continued fraction digits are bounded  - $x = [a_0; a_1, a_2, \dots]$ with $|a_n| \leq M$ he shows:

$$ \left| 1 + 2 \sum q^{n^2} \right| \asymp 
 \sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{1-r}} $$

This is from a the collected papers of Hardy, [[1](https://archive.org/details/CollectedPapersOfG.H.Hardy-Volume1)]

---

This derivation is from page 4 of Hardy's divergent series:

\begin{eqnarray*} \sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{1 - \cos n \theta}{n^2} &=& \sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2} \sum (-1)^k \frac{(n\theta)^{2k+2}}{(2k+2)!} \\
&=& \sum (-1)^k \frac{\theta^{2k+2}}{(2k+2)!} \sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{2k}} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\theta^2( 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots) \\
&=& \frac{\theta^2}{4} \end{eqnarray*}

Then Hardy begins to express concern this derivation can't hold in general:

$$ \sum (-1)^{n-1} \frac{f(\theta)}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{2} a_0 + \frac{\theta^2}{2} a_1 $$

This is not true for $f(\theta) = a_0 + a_1 \theta^2 + a_2 \theta^4 + \dots$ so what gives?

Even though $\sum (-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}$ is clearly right in many circumstances, Hardy shows it can lead to false statements.  How do we reject something which is so right and intuitive?

---

Lastly, Hardy shows the prime number theorem.  The odds of an n-digit number being prime is $\frac{1}{\text{# of digits of } n}$.  Or the average of the Mobius function is $0$... among square-free number half of them have an even number of factors and half of them have an odd number of factors:

$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n \leq N} \mu(n) = o(1) $$

These are proven from **tauberian theorems** although there are several other steps involved.

Comment: Is this result on theta function discussed in Hardy's book on Divergent Series? If not, then in which book?

Comment: The end of your answer makes no sense: you write about $x$ being irrational but then you give an estimate that has no explicit dependence on $x$ anywhere.  What are $q$ and $r$, and how are they related to $x$? Don't assume everyone is going to look up Hardy's book to figure out the notation.

Comment: Sum of $\mu(n)$ is not $o(1)$, it's $o(x)$...

Comment: @johnmangual Can you please make your answer more coherent? In your opinion, is Tauberian Theorems the main take away from Hardy's book on Divergent Series?

Comment: @rationalbeing I can't think of many people who specifically study divergent series or any main take-away of this book.  Hardy seem to collect as many result as he can into one place.  I think Hardy's book shows coherent discussions can be made about divergent series while studying other topics.

Comment: Plenty of divergent series that can be summed by analytic continuation, even just to the boundary of the radius of convergence, do not correspond to a distribution if you take the limit of the distribution of partial sums.

Comment: @DouglasZare i don't claim to be comprehensive or particularly accurate.  these are merely examples I found interesting in Hardy's "Divergent Series" and other works.